# PHP in_array not working

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am using the PHP in_array() function in order to authenticate (with sessions) if a user can access a particular page. For some reason, it is not working...

### PHP PAGE

```
session_start();
require_once('../scripts/functions.php'); 
$role_auth = @$_SESSION['role_auth'];
access($role_auth, array(0,1,2,3,4));
```

### access FUNCTION

```
function access($role_auth, $array){

if(!(in_array($role_auth, $array))){ 
   header("Location: ../index.html");
}
}
```

If I insert print statements in the function, I can see that all of the correct values are being passed into the function. The problem is, if the function is called without a session variable set, for some reason it is considered as being in the array, and it authenticates.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a tip, you can use `range(0,4)` instead of `array(0,1,2,3,4)`. http://php.net/range

Comment: A quick note on your security check. Make sure you call die() or exit() after you send the header, because the content afterward in the script will still be send.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you may want to enable strict type checks by using:

```
in_array($role_auth, $array, true)
```

as what is likely happening is that $role_auth is being eval'd as false and that could match 0 in your in_array statement.

what you SHOULD be doing is this:

```
session_start(); 
require_once('../scripts/functions.php'); 
$role_auth = (isset($_SESSION['role_auth']))?$_SESSION['role_auth']:-1; 
access($role_auth, array(0,1,2,3,4));
```

or something similiar. nothing good ever comes of using the @ operator

Answer (score 3):

I would check to see if $_SESSION['role_auth'] is actually set (with `isset`) instead of using @ to suppress warnings (which is bad practice IMHO)

I think what's happening is that false == 0 ... so `in_array` returns true when nothing is in $role_auth because it sees it as 0 and 0 is in your array

Answer (score 3):

```
 $role_auth = @$_SESSION['role_auth'];
```

The @ sign is suppressing any warnings you might get here, like index is not in array.  How about something like this instead:

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['role_auth']))
    $role_auth = $_SESSION['role_auth'];
 else
    $role_auth = -1;//(or whatever an invalid role is)
```

Comment: The @ is also quite expensive when it comes to performance as php turns error reporting on and off in the background.

Answer (score 3):

In php, the number zero is considered equal to most non-numeric things, for example:

```
null   == 0
false  == 0
""     == 0
"asdf" == 0
```

You probably need to make sure that `$_SESSION` actually contains the `'role_auth'` key beforehand and convert it to the appropriate type, also passing the `$strict` parameter to `in_array`, thus guaranteeing a type check as well as a value check (`===` vs. `==`). Removing zero from your array might also be a good idea.

Comment: this surprises me!, 0 == "asdf" OMFG!! :@

Comment: HOLY SH#t!!, this behaviour affected my entire web app since was created! ( stock and serial codes related ), now i patched this and a consistency check was done... ( all is Ok! )

Seriously, i will nominate Noah Medling to Man of the Year =P